# Dynamic Recipe Instructions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**The Problem:**

I am trying to create a paragraph of recipe instructions with multiple Jquery click events spread throughout the paragraph.  Each event when clicked will pull in a different slide show in a modal window from a mysql database from a table of cooking techniques.

A technique could be slicing tomatoes, dicing onions, etc...  The ultimate goal is to enable individuals to read through a recipe and be able to click on a cooking technique and learn how to do the technique through a slide show of pictures.

**My Solution that Doesn't Work:**

Currently I am nesting multiple  a tags with a unique techniqueID throughout the paragraph, for each click event, which I loaded into a recipeInstructions field in a recipe table in MYSQL. In the HTML on the Recipe Page (source code for recipe Page below) I am doing a query and while loop to pull in the techniqueTitle and techniqueID for each bootstrap modal event(Code Below) which is then sent to a processing page to conduct a mysql query. (The ajax load event code is working fine).

Finally I am trying to use replaceWith to write over the nested a tags with each bootstrap modal event.  I am doing it this way because I don't want to load all the code for each bootstrap modal event in one database field.

PARAGRAPH OF RECIPE INSTRUCTIONS WITH NESTED A Tags

```
<!--RECIPE INSTRUCTIONS -->
<div id="recipe">
  <p>First you need to <a id="3">Chop the Kale</a> Then     
  place the carrots in a bowl<a id="4">Bake the Chicken</a></p> and after it has cooled...
</div>

<!-- TECHNIQUE MODAL TARGET AJAX LOAD FROM processing_techniquePages.php -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-     
labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

CODE FOR BOOTSTRAP MODAL EVENT LOADED AT BOTTOM OF EACH RECIPE PAGE:

```
 <?php while($techniquePages = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) : ?>
    <a 
      id="<?php echo $techniquePages["techniquePagesID"]; ?>"
      href="#"
      data-toggle="modal" 
      data-href="processing_techniquePages.php?techniquePagesID=<?php echo     
      $techniquePages["techniquePagesID"]; ?>" 
      data-target="#myModal2">
      <span class="span-tech-modal">
        <?php echo $techniquePages["techniqueTitle"];?>
      </span>
    </a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

WHILE LOOP OUTPUT FOR BOOTSTRAP MODAL EVENT

```
</div><!-- /.modal .fade-->
//Bootstrap Modal Event that will replace the <a>. 
<div class="insert">
<a
id="3"
href="#"
data-toggle="modal"
data-href="processing_techniquePages.php?techniquePagesID=3"
data-target="#myModal2">
<span class="span-tech-modal">
Chop Kale </span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="insert">
<a
id="4"
href="#"
data-toggle="modal"
data-href="processing_techniquePages.php?techniquePagesID=4"
data-target="#myModal2">
<span class="span-tech-modal">
Baked Chicken </span>
</a>
</div>
```

JQUERY CODE

```
 <script> $(document).ready( function() { 
 var rep = $("#recipe p a #3"); 
 var repObject = $(".insert a #3"); 
 rep.replaceWith("repObject"); }); 
</script>
```

Comment: **Tip:** ID and Name attributes must contain at least one character and not contain any space characters. Your `<a>` tags are using purely numerical ID's. Use something like `ID="teq_1"`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment I will change my IDs.  For some reason the numbers alone did look weird to me but I couldnt figure out why

Comment: I switched the ids to tech_3 and tech_4 but the replace with is not working not sure if replaceWith works with embedded PHP

Comment: The comment, `//Bootstrap Modal Event that will replace the <a>.` does that appear literally on your site? That's not good, because it's not a HTML comment and it contains a start tag.

Comment: Also, you say you are using nested a elements, but I don't see any. You shouldn't nest a elements anyway. However, the irony is that the comment mentioned above _does_ result in a nested a.

Comment: Mr Lister thanks for the reply.  The <a> doesnt appear on the site.  I placed it in the example to show the input I am placing in the database.  I am using the <a id="tech_3"> as a marker to place within the paragraph which I would like to replace with the modal event which when triggered who bring up a slide show of the technique